# Android - ImageView from URL won't fill_parent in ListView

Tags: android, json, image, listview

I have a JSON, I am parsing the JSON. It results with text and an image in a listview.
Everything works fine except one thing.
I am trying to get the ImageView to fill_parent as width and wrap_content as height. This doesn't work..

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/id"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/created_at"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loves"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/created_at"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/comments"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loves"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hypes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/comments"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hypes"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/byline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_flag"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/byline" />
```

And if you need to, this is my Java to show the Image in Listview:
http://pastebin.com/N0j5gjPE

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you need the image to be the full width of its parent?

Comment: @Muhannad Yes, the images are different heights so the width has to fill its parent width and the height depends on the original ratio

Comment: try giving scaleType for the image view as fitXY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_flag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

From the doc:

```
android:adjustViewBounds
Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.
```

Try changing `scaleType="fitCenter"` for `"centerInside"`

if that doesn't work, try this custom ImageView.

```
public class AspectRatioImageView extends ImageView {

public AspectRatioImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = width * getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() / getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

}

and replace ImageView for

```
     <com.package.AspectRatioImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_flag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Comment: This works half. The ratio is good but it doesn't fill the whole width. I changed android:widht="fill_parent" But this doesn't help anything..

Comment: Sure, tell me what kind of problem?

Comment: Since I'm loading images from JSON and they're online I'm using http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/ That is already a custom ImageView so do you know how I can get it working with that? @Chronos

Comment: If you have the Library src code. You can add this lines on the method onMesure:
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = width * getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() / getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

Answer (score 0):

Can You try add this attribute to imageView

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

It will look like

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_flag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abs__ab_bottom_solid_light_holo"

        android:scaleType="fitXY"

        android:layout_below="@+id/byline" />
```

Comment: It's already making progress :D The width is working now, except the height.. Here, have a look: http://i.imgur.com/XswW73R.jpg

Comment: This is because you set wrap_content so it will wrap exactly the image height as is , so try to use another image with height greator than the existing , it will be fine ,

Comment: Hmmm, strange.. The Image I am parsing from JSON is: http://cdn4.lbstatic.nu/files/looks/medium/2013/05/08/3024849_6889.jpg?1368016292 This should have a bigger height..

Comment: I think you should use scrolView

Comment: Where do you mean? @Muhannad

Comment: @user2232286 In the outer layout as parent of your relative layout

Comment: Could it maybe that my Images are made smaller when I parsed them?

Comment: I don't think so ! it depends the dpi as well