# Scale image in RecycleView

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, picasso

I want to scale down the images I show in a **RecyclerView** via **Picasso**, this is how the layout looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#a90180"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/model_image_iv"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is how I load the image in the adapter:

```
Picasso.with(parentActivity)
    .load(BaseApplication.getImageBaseUrl()+image)
    .into(holder.imageView);
```

The image is shown but it doesn't keep the **aspect ratio**. 
I've tried removing `scaleType="centerCrop"` and using `adjustViewBounds="true"` instead, with the same result.

Then I used Picasso's `.fit().centerCrop()` and `.resize(x,y).centerCrop()` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462407/android-imageview-from-url-wont-fill-parent-in-listview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277642/android-fit-imageview-to-listview) SO posts with no luck either.

Does anyone have a hint on this?

Comment: remove android:scaleType="centerCrop" and then try adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: I tried that already and unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: try setting android:scaleType="fitXY" and use resize(300,300) with picasso. might solve your problem

Comment: @sahil-manchanda I tried, but the aspect ratio is not kept

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this](https://gist.github.com/raviteja83/09678b7f086b05e7eb6ecdf0f8eb00d4) instead of ImageView in your layout.it might work.